# open angle brackets in Linear Algebra

Tags: vectors

I know that $\langle v,w \rangle$ denotes the scalar (inner) product of two vectors. But how to interpret $I = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 |
$, where is (I think) the identity matrix and $\sigma_x  = | 1 \rangle \langle 0 | + | 0 \rangle \langle 1 |$ the Pauli X matrix?

Comment: Do a search for bra and ket notation. This is used in quantum mechanics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation